# VBA Inter-Relationships between Worksheet, UserForm, and Radio Button

Tags: vba, radio-button, userform

I am trying to get the response when OptionButton1 is true.  I have done everything I know to do, but still something is missing.

I created a UserForm and added an OK button, and a radio button.  I added a Class Module for button click.  I added the code-behind to execute the UserForm.  Still the button is not active.

1. I have this in a Class Module with "btn" selected in the left drop down box, and "click" selected in the right one:

   ```
   Private WithEvents btn As CommandButton
   ```
2. Added a process flow manager in a regular module:

   ```
   Sub DataFromUserForm_Manager()
       Call CreateUserForm
       Call Add_OptionButton
   End Sub
   ```
3. Added the UserForm and the code-behind:

   ```
   Sub CreateUserForm()

       Dim myForm As Object
       Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
       Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton
       Dim NewCommandButtonl As MSForms.CommandButton
       Dim NewCommandButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton

       'This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
       Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

       Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

      'Create the User Form
       With myForm
          .Properties("Caption") = "Form 091619"
          .Properties("Width") = 300
          .Properties("Height") = 150
          .Properties("Name") = "UserForm1"
       End With

       'Create commandButton for "OK"
       Set NewCommandButtonl = 
       myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.CommandButton.1", "OK", True)

       With NewCommandButtonl
          .Caption = "OK"
          .Height = 30
          .Width = 100
          .Left = 50
          .Top = 10
       End With

       'OK button code-behind
       myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 9, "Private Sub btnOK_Click()"
       myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 10, "    If OptionButton1.Value = 
           True Then"
       myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 11, "         Range(Cells(11, 3), 
           Cells(11, 2)).Value = 5"
       myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines 12, "End Sub"

   End With

   End Sub
   ```
4. Added the radio button:

   ```
   Sub Add_OptionButton()

       Dim btn As MSForms.OptionButton

      'Add OptionButton and assign it to object 'OpBtn'
       Set btn = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")

       'Assign OptionButton Name
       btn.Caption = ""
       btn.Name = "OptionButton1"

       'OptionButton Position
       btn.Left = 50
       btn.Top = 75

       UserForm1.Show

   End Sub
   ```
5. Here is the OK button code-behind from behind the UserForm:

   ```
   Private Sub btnOK_Click()
       If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
           Range(Cells(11, 3), Cells(11, 2)).Value = 5
   End Sub
   ```

No error message.  Code runs ok, and displays UserForm1 with the "OK" button and the OptionButton.  Button does not result in execution of the behind-code.
+Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of the class module at the top of your listing?  You seem to be mixing two different approaches to creating a dynamic userform.

Comment: i second the comment by @Tim Williams and see no need to use class module, VBE is already been used. The problem may be button name. If the Button name is "OK", then may correct button name from `btnOK` to `OK` in the VBE `InsertLines` command.

Comment: Depending on the use case(s) for this it might be "better" to use the class-based approach to event handling, if only to avoid the potential headaches connected to dynamic code insertion via VBE, and the need to have the "Trust access to VBProject" setting checked.

Comment: Does "Class Based Event Handling" mean to put the event process codes in a Class Module and in the click code on the form refer to the Class Module for processing?

Comment: Ted:  Thanks for your comments.  To your first comment, I'm not very sure of what I am doing here.  I read somewhere that was what was needed, so I did it.  All the information I found is piece-meal, and I have not found a complete description of how to do this. My post might be the most complete description out there.

Comment: Yes I mean put all the event-handling code in your class module.  FYI there are plenty of posts here on SO with full examples, or try googling "VBA control array"